# Inconsistent mediadevice behavior on headless Chrome with `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` flag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, chromium, getusermedia

I'm running into some seemingly inconsistent behavior with headless Chrome. I'm trying to use the `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` flag to test media devices on a domain other than `localhost` with headless Chrome.

The problem is that when Chrome is run normally, the media devices work as expected, but when running it headless, they fail to load.

HTML I'm testing with (`media.html`):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <video id="video"></video>

    <script>
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: {width: 1280, height: 720}})
      .then(function(stream) {
        var video = document.querySelector('#video');
        video.srcObject = stream;

        video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
          video.play();
        };
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log("Failed to get media devices");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Running Chrome the following results in it working as expected:

```
chromium --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://lvh.me:8000 --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --remote-debugging-port=9222 "http://lvh.me:8000/media.html"
```

Using `python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` as the web server.

However, running Chrome in headless mode:

```
chromium --headless --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://lvh.me:8000 --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --remote-debugging-port=9222 "http://lvh.me:8000/media.html"
```

And then going to `http://localhost:9222/` results in the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined
    at media.html:9
```

Does anyone know where this inconsistency is coming from? Why does headless Chrome seemingly not respect the `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this issue filed a few months ago: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=828266&q=unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Looks like this a bug with Chrome.